# how to unset session in javascript on slider change

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

How can I unset a session using javscript. I know this can't be done in javascript alone but we have to call a php script. I want to unset the session on the change of my sldier value. i.e.

```
 $('#slider1').bind('change', function (event) {
                        $('#slider1Values').html('Value: ' + event.args.value.toFixed(2));
                   //I want to unset the session here
                    });
```

I found some post where we can unset it in a button click by redirecting to another php page where I can call the php script to unset the session. I want something which unsets a session on the change of the slider without redirecting it into another page if possible. I saw it can be done using ajax but could not find an example. If any links or source please provide. Is this possible by doing?

```
var a=<?php  unset($_SESSION['data']);?>;
```

Comment: use `session_destroy()`

Comment: You should also ajax that calls a page called `logout.php`, where it does the `session_destroy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if jquery is on the table then it's pretty easy to perform a session value unset.

First off create a php file that does the actual unset

```
<?php 
// unset_data.php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["data"]);
?>
```

Then on your change event from the slider.

```
$('#slider1').bind('change', function (event) {
     $('#slider1Values').html('Value: ' + event.args.value.toFixed(2));
     $.ajax("/unset_data.php", {"cache":false});
}
```

Comment: Thanks what exactly does $.post or $.get do?Is it similar to redirecting the page to unset_data.php?

Comment: it makes either a ajax get or post request, so it calls the script file without reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Why should we do the last part for {"cache":false}? Can you explain it please.

Comment: Just like any other request your browser will cache AJAX Requests. This prevents the browser from caching and trying to serve up a cached response instead of hitting your PHP file like you need it to.